# Showing the inverse of A is A*

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, adjoint-operators

Question: Let $A ∈ M_n(F)$ be a matrix whose columns form an orthonormal basis for $F$
$n \times 1$ under
the dot product.

> Show $A$ is invertible and the inverse of $A$ is $A^∗$.

Attempt: Showing $A$ is invertible is trivial enough since its columns form an ON basis, but my class hasn't touched on adjoints much, so I am not sure how to proceed to show that $A^{-1} = A^*$.

Comment: To compute the $i,j$ entry of $A A^*$, you take the dot product of the $i^\text{th}$ row of $A$ and the $j^\text{th}$ column of $A^*$. $A^*$ is the conjugate transpose of $A$, so its columns are the conjugates of the rows of $A$.

Comment: @ViktorVaughn But it is the columns that are known to be orthonormal, so presumably one should consider the product $A^*A$ instead

Comment: @BenGrossmann Oops, my mistake.